# HP DL380G5 with APC SC1500 UPS -- transfer time failure

Tags: hp-proliant, electrical-power, power-supply-unit, apc-smart-ups

I have 2 of these things: APC SmartUPS SC1500 (220v). My Proliant G5 DL380 PSUs seem to really hate them. This is what happens when UPS switches to battery (PSU2 is plugged into the SC1500):

iLo IML log:

```
</>hpiLO-> show system1/log1/record2
    severity=NonCritical
    date=06/06/2013
    time=07:32
    description=System Power Supply: General Failure (Power Supply 2)

</>hpiLO-> show system1/log1/record3
    severity=NonCritical
    date=06/06/2013
    time=07:32
    description=System Power Supplies Not Redundant
```

Every single time the SC1500 goes on battery, PSU goes dark then quickly back up again. If i plug PSU1 into the SC1500, same result.

I did some reading (really nice stuff BTW),
http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c02492972/c02492972.pdf
http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/93413-hp-ml350-g6-vs-apc-1500-ups

i have older SmartUPSes from APC (SU1400RMI2U) which either put out a better sine or have a faster transfer time because the PSUs in the DL380 acts very natural when they switch over to battery.

Aren't all SmartUPSes supposed to put out a clean sine?

I'm going to bring my Tektronix from home and check just how much of a sine is the SC1500's output really, but i was just wondering if this is a common problem with the SC1500 or i've been delivered some duds.

Comment: Sounds like a defective UPS. You should call APC if it's under warranty.

Comment: This isn't normal. You've answered your own question, though. Use a different UPS.

Comment: Oh man the other SC1500 is doing the same thing. Just tested.

Answer (score 2):

Well then, let me answer to my own question properly.

SC1500 -- https://www.apc.com/products/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=SC1500I

> Waveform Type: **Stepped approximation** to a sinewave

SUA1400 (the one that works) -- http://www.apc.com/products/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=SU1400RMI2U

> Waveform Type: Sine wave

I guess the PFC in the HP power supplies isn't very found of `pixelated` sine waves.
Next time i'll be more careful with my power.